# FFMpeg create thumbnail from HLS Live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, live, http-live-streaming

I would like to create a thumbnail for HLS stream.
I am doing it already with mp4 files
like this `ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:10.000 -i file.mp4 -vframes 1 -vf scale=256:144 out.jpg`

And it works great.

But when I try it with HLS live stream, it just spams

```
Opening 'liveX.ts' for reading.
```

Even though 10th second is in 'live1.ts'

Any solution to this? And I would like if duration is not in stream, just report error.

Comment: What's your command for extraction?

Comment: Exactly like in mp4 so
`ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:10.000 -i live.m3u8 -vframes 1 -vf scale=256:144 out.jpg`

Comment: @Gyan any idea how to do it, or if it is possible with ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I was working with FFMPEG today to see how this could be done with a live stream.  I discovered that it can be done pretty easily.
Here is what I use...

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i http://username:password@[hls feed ip address]/[path.m3u8] -s 800x450 -vframes 1 -f image2 -updatefirst 1 MyThumbnail.jpg
```

This is similar to the way you get a thumbnail from an rtsp stream, but seems to work faster.

I hope this helps someone.